# Loader and LoaderManager - how to determine if a current Loader is active and running?

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

How can you query a LoaderManager to see if a Loader is currently running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible situations of doing it:

### 1st case

If you use **the only Loader** or you have several but you don't care which one of them is running:

```
getSupportLoaderManager().hasRunningLoaders()
```

### 2nd case

You want to know whether some particular `Loader` is running. It seems it's not supported by SDK, but you can easily implement it on your own.

#### a) Just add the flag

```
public class SomeLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String[]> {

    public boolean isRunning;

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        isRunning = true;
        super.onStartLoading();
        //...
        forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(String[] data) {
        super.deliverResult(data);
        isRunning = false;
    }
    //...
}
```

#### b) and use it (a bit tricky) :-)

```
SomeLoader loader = (SomeLoader) manager.<String[]>getLoader(ID);
Log.d(TAG, "isRunning: " + loader.isRunning);
```

The key reason I have posted it here - it's a tricky enough call of a generic method before casting a `Loader` to your `SomeLoader`.

## Reminder

Whatever you do if you call `getSupportLoaderManager.restartLoader` your current task (if it's running) is not being killed. So the next step will be a call of `onCreateLoader` which will create a new `Loader`. So it means that you can have 2,3,4,5 and more the same tasks parallel tasks together (if you don't prevent it in some way) that can lead to a battery draining and an exceed CPU/network load.

Answer (score 1):

I do think Slava has a good solution, but I have an improvement for his 'tricky' part:

Create an interface:

```
public interface IRunnableLoader {
    boolean IsRunning();
}
```

Let the `SomeLoader` class implement the interface:

```
public class SomeLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String[]> implements IRunnableLoader {

    private boolean isRunning;

    public SomeLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        isRunning = true;
        super.onStartLoading();
        //...
        forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(String[] data) {
        super.deliverResult(data);
        isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean IsRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }
    //...
}
```

... and use it like this:

```
Loader<String> loader = getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(TASK_ID);
if (loader instanceof IRunnableLoader && ((IRunnableLoader)loader).IsRunning()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "is Running");
}
else {
    Log.d(TAG, "is not Running");
}
```

BTW Casting a variable is only safe when the loader doesn't change to some other type in another thread. If, in your program, the loader can change in another thread then use the `synchronized` keyword somehow.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
getLoaderManager().getLoader(id)
```

if exist return the loader, then call `isStarted()` to check it's running.